# Why the number of call during one 1 hours follow Poisson distribution with parameters $48$.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Suppose that a compagnie has in average $48$ calls each hours. How many calls the compagnie has in average in $24$ hours.

**Attempts**

Let $X_n$ the numbers of call during time $n$ and $n+1$ for $n\in \{0,...,23\}$. Each $X_n$ are independent, and thus, the average of the numbers of call in $24$ hours is $24\mathbb E[X_1]$.

---

In the solution of my exercise, they say that $X_n$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $48$, and thus the number of calls in $24$ hours is in means $1152$. But I don't understand why $X_n$ follow a Poisson distribution with parameters $48$. My teacher assistant said that the numbers of call in one hours is a rare event, but I'm not sos satisfied but it in the sense that $48$ calls in $1$ hours, is not so rare...

Comment: Seems like that is an assumption your instructor wants to make.  A priori, of course, it is possible that the $X_n$ satisfy a different distribution (indeed, nothing in the problem statement suggests that they should all satisfy the same distribution)/

Comment: Side note:  I wouldn't think the "equally distributed" assumption is at all realistic, for example.  Presumably the company gets *a lot* more calls during business hours than it does over night, for example.  But for a math problem one is free to assume all sorts of things, so long as those assumptions are clearly stated.

Comment: Whatever the distribution, calls per hour times number of hours = number of calls.

Comment: Given that there are 3600000 milliseconds in an hour, 48 events do qualify as rare.

Comment: The argument in "Attempt" becomes correct once you strike the remark about independence. Rather, you have $\Bbb E[X_0]=\cdots =\Bbb E[X_{23}]=48$ and thus $\Bbb E[X_0+\cdots+X_{23}]=\Bbb E[X_1]+\cdots +\Bbb E[X_{23}]=24\cdot 48$.

Comment: The way I would see it; if you ask the question : divide 1 hours in 60 minutes. Then define $Y_i$ being $1$ if we have a call at $i-th$ minutes and $0$ otherwise and $Y_i$ being independent with parameter $24/30$. Then $X=Y_1+...+Y_{60}$ will follow a $Binom(60,24/30)$ which can be approximated (badly) with a $poisson(60\cdot 24/30)= poisson(48)$. Now, if you separate it not in minute, but in second, then the approximation will be better....

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I can mistaken, but in my lecture, I can approximate a $Binom(n,p_n)$ with a $Poisson(np_n)$ for $np_n\leq 10$. I'm I mistaken something ? Here $np_n=48>10$... which is big

Comment: @Surb: See my previous comment : I can mistaken, but in my lecture, I can approximate a $Binom(n,p_n)$ with a $Poisson(np_n)$ for $np_n\leq 10$. I'm I mistaken something ? Here $np_n=48>10$... which is big

Comment: Well...who says the "true" distribution is binomial?  Perhaps a call comes in every $\frac {60}{48}$ of a minute like clockwork.   Like I said, I'd be far more concerned about the "identical distribution" assumption than with the form of the distribution.  Assuming Poisson just means assuming  something along the lines of "any number of calls is possible in any given time interval and the distribution of calls in a time interval $I$ depends only on the length of $I$, not on its exact timing".  Within a given hour, that sounds sensible (to me).

Comment: Should say:  the exact form of the distribution is largely irrelevant here.  If you imagine that the $48$ means "the average number of calls received per hour in a typical day" and the question then asked "what's the expected number of calls received in a typical day?" then the answer is just $48\times 24$, by the definition of average.  Still making assumptions regarding the precise meaning of some of the informal terms in the statement, but there's no need to specify the distribution further.

Comment: I indeed agree with @lulu... with the model I took before, you can't have several call at the same minute, so dividing one hour in 3600 second allows you now to have several call in the same minute, but not at the same second... you can continue farther, but you will always have this kind of problem (but in a unit of time that is of the order of $\frac{1}{60^n}$). However, in your situation, nothing prevent you from having 7 calls at the same time... so at the end, it's what the Poisson distribution allows you to do... sort of smoothing the binomial law...